# Access IPython's profile history (history.sqlite)

Tags: ipython

When I restart IPython, I can access the input from my last session by pressing the up- and down-keys. I found that the history specific to a profile is saved in `~/.config/ipython/profile_profilename/history.sqlite`.

Is there a way to access this history in the same easy fashion as the %history command?

The IPython reference describes the feature here: http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/reference.html#readline-based-features
This guy has the same question, but they don't find a 'direct' solution: http://python.6.n6.nabble.com/Logging-in-new-IPython-td1665151.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean a tool to access your history from the outside IPython, perhaps from the command line?

The API to do it is already there - see the class `IPython.core.history.HistoryAccessor` ([source code](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/IPython/core/history.py#L65)). There's [an example script (updated link)](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/examples/core/ipython-get-history.py) showing how you can use it to dump a session from the database. But we haven't yet made an application around that. If you're interested in it, you could work on that - see our list of [potential projects for contributors to start](http://wiki.ipython.org/Potential_projects).

Comment: Excellent, thank you! The project sounds interesting, I'll think about it.

Comment: How to load a dumped session?