# Where does ipython store the current session history?

Tags: ipython

I use vim with a couple of plugins as a python ide. Along with an open vim session, I run an ipython session in a split console. I've found their combination is a great productivity tool for programming data analysis scripts.

What I'm missing is a way to show all current session history in a side panel, so that I could easily do some copy-pasting from there to the vim session to create a script. Something similar to 'tail -f' would do, if only I knew where ipython stores the current session history.

I already know:

- ipython has '%history' and 'hist' commands, BUT I'm looking for a way to display the history in a panel outside of the ipython session.
- history is stored in a sqlite file under .ipython/(profile), BUT I don't know how to access that file.

I hope I've been clear about my question. 
Thanks in advance for all your help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access IPython's profile history (history.sqlite)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12261492/access-ipythons-profile-history-history-sqlite)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer Amit, but I could not find an answer to my question in the link you provide. Moreover, following your link, the "example link" offered in that page cannot be found. It seems as the project was abandoned or (hopefully) changed location. Thanks again.

Comment: Recent search of the terms "ipython get history" gave me this link, which could be of use to others as well: http://www.hep.caltech.edu/~piti/share/doc/ipython/examples/core/ipython-get-history.py

Answer (score 0):

You can output your history with the commands

> %history -f filename

history with lines and sessions

> %history -g -f filename

Answer (score 0):

On windows, it is stored in a sqlite database, in

```
%Home%\.ipython\profile_default\history.sqlite
```

If the %home% variable is not set, try %userprofile% instead.

As an example, if you'd like to look back at your very first ipython session, you could run

```
select source from history where session = 1
```